# Empty CSV file after recode via BATCH

Tags: batch-file, encode

I would like to recode a CSV File from UCS 2 Little Endian to UTF-8 via BATCH, but if I start the BATCH it creates the secound file which is empty..

Any idea why? or how to fix it?

```
iconv -f UCS-2 -t UTF-8 -c export_RV-RP.csv > export_RV-RP2.csv
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my PC hasn't installed the ICONV.dll.

So here is the way to fix that.:
1.) http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libiconv/ Download the latest libiconv zip.
2.) Put the Batch including the file into the Bin Folder
3.) Thats it :)